# Estimate distribution through partial observations

Tags: distributions, estimation

I am working on the following problem and I don't know where to even start. Say that I have a random variable $X$ whose distribution is given by an unkown $F$. I have the following sampling process:

1. For $n = 1,\dots, N$ draw $x_n$ from $F$. We do *not* observe $x_n$.
2. Given $x_n$, draw $J_n$ (some number that might differ with $n$) observations $z_1,\dots, z_{J_n}$ from a *known* distribution $G|x_n$ with mean $x_n$ and known finite variance. We only observe the mean value of said observations: $\bar z_n = \frac{1}{J_n}\sum_{j=1}^{J_n} z_j  $

The objective is to empirically recover $F$. One straightforward way would be to treat the $\bar z_1, \dots \bar z_N$ as our observations and apply any kernel distribution estimation available. However, it seems that we have more information available, as we know our estimates differs in its precision and that should be taken into consideration.

Any ideas on how to proceed to this?

Thanks!

Comment: This resembles the "Bayes Deconvolution" problem. http://statweb.stanford.edu/~ckirby/brad/talks/2014BayesDeconvolution.pdf

Comment: It seems to be exactly that, thanks a lot. If you want to give a small answer I can validate a solution.

Comment: Although Brad Efron's lecture deals with constructing or "recovering" a distribution with incomplete information.  I am not sure that it has the same objective that you have.  He is dealing with a specific relationship been prior and posterior distributions that have a special relationship via Bayes Theorem.  Although I am not completely clear about your problem, I do not see where your G and F are related as prior and posterior distributions.

Comment: My understanding is that $(X,Z)$ have an underlying joint distribution where we are interested in the marginal distribution of $X$, which is $F$ given all possible values for the signals. One might relate the two by thinking that the marginal of $X$ is the unknown prior from which, conditional on a realization of $X=x$, we draw signals from a known likelihood. The approach in this case would be to (somehow) estimate the prior.